# WooCommerce message hook after add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, action, cart

After clicking on the button Add to basket I have a message -

> " product name " added to the cart successfully.

BEFORE THE PRODUCTS  I want to add another custom message *(for reference I have added a screenshot)*.

What hook should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
/**
 * Custom Add To Cart Messages
 * Add this to your theme functions.php file
 **/
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_add_to_cart_message' );
function custom_add_to_cart_message() {
    global $woocommerce;
    // Output success messages
    if (get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')=='yes') :
        $return_to  = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'));
        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __('Continue Shopping &rarr;', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
    else :
        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('cart')), __('View Cart &rarr;', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
    endif;
        return $message;
}
/* Custom Add To Cart Messages */
```

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/ChromeOrange/3423933)

Answer (score -1):

Here you can try this hook:

[Cart Notices Woocommerce](https://therichpost.com/cart-notices-woocommerce)

Hope this helps you...